# Facing the error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'BBDN' is undefined in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am facing the following errors while running the dotnet application
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'BBDN' is undefined
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'YAHOO' is undefined

I had declared at the top of page as below:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="busyboxdotnet" Namespace="BusyBoxDotNet" Assembly="BusyBoxDotNet" %>
```

and in html tags I have mentioned the following code in the .aspx page:

```
<busyboxdotnet:busybox id="BusyBox" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="50px" Text=" " Overlay="False"
            ShowBusyBox="OnLoad" Image="GreenBar"></busyboxdotnet:busybox><busyboxdotnet:busybox id="BusyBox2" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="50px" Text=" " Image="GreenBar"></busyboxdotnet:busybox>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="BusyBoxDotNet.axd?res=BBDN.js$YAHOO.js$dom.js$event.js$animation.js$BrowserSniff.js$Common.js$BusyBox.js"></script>
```

But I am not getting why this error is coming?
Can anybody will help me?

Comment: I too searched a lot for a fix and the only place i found a bit puny help is : http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2006/07/03/137.aspx Please let know if it was useful.